# Landau-Lifshitz pseudotensor derivation

Tags: general-relativity, resource-recommendations, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I am looking for an explicit derivation of Landau-Lifshitz (Vol. II chap.96) [pseudotensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy%E2%80%93momentum_pseudotensor). It is quite long-expression and in the book by the authors, the proof is left for the reader's own. Are there some notes, well-known sources where it is derived explicitly?

Comment: Perhaps you should specify the volume and the topic, since L&L are full if tensors

Comment: Volume II, in the original book it is called energy-momentum pseudotensor.

Comment: Have a look at a book by Synge, *Relativity: the General Theory* (1960), it goes into more details.

Comment: I can't find pdf version of the book? Do you know where to get the ebook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a book by Synge, Relativity: The General Theory. On the way to derive the Landau-Lifshitz pseudotensor the expression $(154)$ must be derived from $(153)$. $U^{ijkm}$ has the same symmetry properties as the Riemann tensor $R^{ijkm}$. What symmetry property is used to obtain $(154)$?

[image]

Comment: This seems more like a follow-up question than like an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can look in my sites https://lantonov.blogspot.com/2012/02/landau-lifshitz-pseudotensor.html and https://lantonov.tripod.com/Landau-Lifshitz_pseudotensor.html. The first is derivation with Mathematica, and the second is manual. Unfortunately both are incomplete, as they do not contain the derivation in terms of metric densities. I have a more complete derivation in a Matematica notebook form where metric density (equation 96,9) and Synge's derivation is obtained but I need time to translate the notebook to HTML.

**Update:** Now the text in the [blogspot blog](https://lantonov.blogspot.com/2012/02/landau-lifshitz-pseudotensor.html) is complete and it is in a [preprint](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/368287454_Landau-Lifshitz_stress-energy_pseudotensor). Sorry for not putting the derivation. The only reason is that it is too long. And the question is about pointing sources not copying the derivation.